# Force stop container subscribtion (Meteor+React+CreateContainer)

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

How can I manually stop the subscription and clean the collection on the client when you  switch route via react-router?

The fact is that if I go to the page where there is a component subscribed to, such as "top 10 news" page, where published all the news, I see, as a container of news component performing a normal search the collection first finds objects with subscription last page.

```
export default createContainer((props)=>{
    let {limitCount, userId} = props;
    let query = (userId)?{'userId':userId}:{};
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('news_preview', query,limitCount);
    var posts = Post.find(query, {sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch(); //Here, the container finds documents to which another component has been signed.
    var needWait = !!handle.ready()&&!!posts; 
    return {
      needWait:!needWait,
      posts:posts
    }
  }, PostList)
```

After a moment, the container will complete its membership and will give us the relevant objects ...
How can I check that when linking the previous container has stopped its subscription and deleted objects?

In details. With the logic description

**PostListContainer** 
This is a sample of NewsList component, with infinity scroll and subscribtion container. Is just detect scroll, and pass limitCount to child component.

```
export default class PostListContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      limitCount:10,
    }
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, false);
  }
  handleScroll(event) {
    let documentHeight = $(document).height(); //jquery is bad idea, i know
    let windowHeight = $(window).height();
    let scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    let isLoading = this.refs.PostList.data.needWait;
    if(scrollPosition+windowHeight>=documentHeight && !isLoading){
      this.uppendSkipCount()
    }

  }
  uppendSkipCount(){
    let limitCount = this.state.limitCount;
    this.setState({
      limitCount:limitCount+5
    });
  }
  render(){
    let userId = (this.props.userId)?this.props.userId:undefined;
    return(
      <div>
        <PostList ref="PostList" limitCount={this.state.limitCount} userId={userId} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**PostList**
This component get properties, subscribe and render child components.

```
export  class PostList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }
    postList(){
      return(
        <Masonry>
          {this.props.posts.map((post)=>(
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={post._id}>
              <PostPreview  post={post}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Masonry>
      )
    }
    render() {
        let content = (this.props.posts)?this.postList():undefined;
        let loading = (this.props.needWait)?<Loading />:undefined;
        return(
          <div>
            {content}
            {loading}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default createContainer((props)=>{
    let {limitCount, userId} = props;
    let query = (userId)?{'userId':userId}:{};
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('news_preview', query,limitCount);
    var posts = Post.find(query, {sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch();
    var needWait = !!handle.ready()&&!!posts;
    return {
      needWait:!needWait,
      posts:posts
    }
  }, PostList)
```

And it work goood. But if i will come on the page from page that contain for example **BestNews** component i will get Posts object from that in first iteration:(

```
export class BestNews extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
     this.props.handle.stop(); / looks like it help
    }
    goToPage(post){
      browserHistory.push(`/news/item/${post._id}`);
    }
    bestPosts(){
      return bestPosts = this.props.posts.map((post)=>{
        return(
          <div key={post._id}>
          <ListItem
            onTouchTap={()=>this.goToPage(post)}
            leftAvatar={<Avatar src={post.author().getAvatar().link()} />}
            rightIcon ={<ActionChromeReaderMode />}
            primaryText={post.title}
            secondaryText={post.description}
            />
          <Divider />
          </div>
        )
      });
    }
    render() {
        let content = (this.props.needWait)?<Loading />:this.bestPosts();
        return (
          <div className="box-margin">
            <Paper zDepth={1}>
                <div className="row middle-xs center-xs">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <h2 style={{fontWeight:'300'}}>Интересные новости</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row start-xs">
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <List>
                            <Divider />
                            {content}
                        </List>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Paper>
          </div>
          )

    }
  }

export default createContainer((props)=>{
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('best_news');
    var posts = Post.find({}, {sort:{likes:-1}, limit:5}).fetch();
    var needWait = !handle.ready() && !posts;
    return {
      handle:handle,
      needWait:needWait,
      posts:posts
    }
  }, BestNews)
```

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for this in Meteor, see [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3194) for details. That thread suggests some alternative approaches, such as adding metadata to some of the publications (e.g, you "top posts") and querying on that.

Comment: I found a solution.
It was obvious. But somehow it seems to me that there is a better one.
In this case, we need to use a child component of the container. With method componentWillUnmount() we can manually stop the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with manualy stop subscribtion is not good. You understand why.

Take a look at the pretty good solution. 
We need to protect themselves from the fact that when you visit a component we can get irrelevant data with other components. Yes type have the same data, but - with the other components. It can play a cruel joke with s. I think you understand why.

At the same time we can not put a cap "loading" every time a user scrolls down and loaded data. Because at the time of subscription, all data will disappear. Option with named subscriptions you too are not satisfied. For example, if you are using Astronomy ORM by Jagi.

So. We need simply to intercept getting values ​​from the container and once finished to record the fact of the first subscription in the state of the component.

```
export  class PostList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        firstSubscribtion:false
      }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(!this.state.firstSubscribtion && nextProps.handleReady){
        this.setState({
          firstSubscribtion:true
        });
      }
    }
    postList(){
      return(
        <Masonry>
          {this.props.posts.map((post)=>(
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" key={post._id}>
              <PostPreview  post={post}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Masonry>
      )
    }
    render() {
        let content = (this.props.posts && this.state.firstSubscribtion)?this.postList():undefined;
        let loading = (this.props.needWait)?<Loading />:undefined;
        return(
          <div>
            {content}
            {loading}
          </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default createContainer((props)=>{
    let {limitCount, userId} = props;
    let query = (userId)?{'userId':userId}:{};
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('news_preview', query,limitCount);
    var posts = Post.find(query, {sort:{createdAt:-1}}).fetch();
    var needWait = !!handle.ready()&&!!posts;
    return {
      handleReady:!!handle.ready(),
      needWait:!needWait,
      posts:posts
    }
  }, PostList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

It was obvious. But somehow it seems to me that there is a better one.

In this case, we need to use a child component of the container. With method componentWillUnmount() we can manually stop the subscription.

What is negative? The fact that we need to transfer the subscription object in a child component, and then manually stop the subscription. And to do it in each component, which can cause a similar problem.

The answer to the question - why can not we just wait for the completion of the subscription of the container, and then - to display the content. The answer is - it is possible, but as long as you have not implemented infinite scrolling logic. Otherwise, each time the user scrolls down the content will be lost. As long as the subscription is completed.

It's funny, but I always thought that the container so stops the subscription. I was wrong?

Comment: The container stops the subscription when it is unmounted.

Comment: In my case - no:(
I don't' know why.

Everything works fine, but if I stop a subscription manually.

Comment: Then show more of your code or upload a simple reproduction to GitHub.

Comment: I updated the question with code...Can you take a look please?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable, but I am not really familiar with ReactRouter. You are not waiting for the subscription to be ready before rendering. In addition, a subscription takes a short time to remove the documents when `stop()` is called, so it is not surprising that you get some incorrect data. You can try to subscribe with an `onStop` callback that is called when the subscription is stopped (note: not when the data is removed, but when the `unsub` DDP message is sent to the server) and track what is going on, to make sure that the container indeed asks for it to be unsubscribed.

Comment: Yeah. I don't waiting for sub.ready in this case, cause if i will - all content will disappear while subscribtion going every time, when user scroll down. It is a bad. 

React Router have hooks, but catch subscribtions, find needed and stop it manualy looks like a weird idea. So, i found a pretty good solution for InfinityScroll components. 

Will post it in ask.